# Where are the asp.net Dynamic Data limits?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

What are the limitations of asp.net dynamic data?
What is not possible to do in dynamic data, so that you have to use web forms?

Comment: It is not possible to localize the error messages in the meta data.    [Range(5, 50, **ErrorMessage** = "The product's reorder level must be greater than 5 and less than 50")]
         public object ReorderLevel { get; set; }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean DD just sits on top standard ASP.Net site so you can switch in an out of DD, the really great flexibility is that you can just use the bits of DD you need in your ASP.Net project (you don't need to scaffold the site) you can just make use of the business rules and FieldTemplate to speed developement of you site. For instance in a DetailsView when editing a table getting a dropdown list to select from a related table is always a pain in ASp.Net but is mix in a little DD you get that for free. :D
see my blog here [Custom Pages Part 3 - Standard ASP.Net Page with Dynamic Data features added to take advantage of the FieldTemplates.](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/07/part-3-standard-aspnet-page-with.html)

Comment: +1 that was not clear to me: "DD just sits on top standard ASP.Net site"